# Visual studio Team foundation corrupted file

Tags: git, visual-studio

My machine crashed in the midst of a Team Foundation sync, and now when I try to commit changes, or change branches in my solution, I get the error:

```
An error occurred. Detailed message: Invalid data in index - incorrect header signature
```

How can I get my commits/sync working again?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the entire folder and pulling it in again? Maybe back-up your changes first?

Comment: Attempted, but I get timeout errors and it will not clone the remote repo. (It is 7Gb) I have cloned it before, though, so it is strange!

Comment: Am I able to adjust the timeout buffer settings for the clone?

Comment: Did you try to clone from Visual Studio or from the commandline?

Comment: Visual studio. I will try from GITGUI. Then, do I just open the .sln from that folder in VS, and commit?

Comment: Git gives me: fatal: early EOF
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: index-pack failed
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200

Comment: Maybe try uninstalling and reinstalling Git as a last resort? Or maybe use a new project, since the structure of your old one seems screwed up. I'm a newbie though, so there are probably better options

Comment: It sounds like an issue at the server side.

Comment: What TFS version and what VS version? what's the version of the git command line?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue yesterday. I resolved this by disconnecting the database from source control then re added it.